# Test that a record is a duplicate of another record in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

In my Rails app tested with RSpec, I'm testing a function that [calls `.dup()`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-dup) on some records and saves the duplicates. How can I test that the newly created records are duplicates of the expected original records?

I doubt there's an assertion for this specific case. And I can always make sure that the duplicate and original records have the same values for their attributes but are different records. I'm wondering if there's a more elegant, accepted pattern for this kind of test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `have_attributes` assertion.

```
match_attributes = first_user.attributes.except(:id, :created_at, :updated_at)

expect(second_user).to have_attributes(match_attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go about it like so:

```
 it 'creates a duplicate' do 
    record = Record.find(1) 
    new_record = record.dup
    new_record.save 
    expect(Record.where(id: [record.id,new_record.id], 
           **new_record.attributes.except(:id, :created_at, :updated_at)
           ).count
    ).to eq 2
 end
```

This should quantify the duplication and persistence of both records in one shot.